# Alternate way of providing Credentials to Spring Cloud GCP

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gcp

I am trying to use the Spring Cloud GCP. I want to know how to programmatically load GCP credentials rather than loading the GCP credentials from a json file using `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location` .

Does creating a bean of type `com.google.auth.Credentials` let Spring-Boot auto-configure Spring-Cloud-GCP correctly to use within the application?

If not, what is the way to inject Credentials so that Spring Cloud GCP is configured correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not `Credentials`, but a bean of type `CredentialsProvider` [will take precedence over any properties/autoconfiguration](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/2.0.5/reference/html/index.html#credentials).

It's a functional interface, so you can return a lambda:

```
        @Bean
        public CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider() {
            return () -> NoCredentialsProvider.create().getCredentials();
        }
```